# How can I generate half-normal variates in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, probability

I can find the

```
random('normal', 0, 1, 10000,1)
```

command in MATLAB but it generates half-normal variates. I would like to generate random half-normal variates. The half-normal distribution is defined by

$$f_{|Z|}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^{2}}{2}.$$

Can I generate a random half-normal variates from random normal variates?

Comment: Recommend adding "Truncate" or "Truncation" tag.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I don't think those tags (neither _truncation_ nor _normal-distribution_) would increase the content visibility and improve the question on CompSci SE.

Answer (score 10):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) says, you can just compute a normally distributed random variable with a mean of zero and take the absolute value. The half-normal probability distribution function is identical to the normal PDF with $\mu = 0$ for $X > 0$, except for a factor of two for the normalization.

Answer (score 4):

If $X\sim \text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$, then the $Y\sim \text{Half-Normal}$ is obtainable via several approaches.

1. **Absolute Value:**   $\quad Y = |X|\quad $ (As pointed out by @DavidZ.)
2. **Truncation:**   $\quad Y = X_{(0,\infty)} \quad $ MATLAB does this nicely with [`truncate()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.truncate.html).
3. **Conditioning (Logical Indexing):** $\quad Y = (X|X>0)\quad $

Graphical examples below with code.
[image: Truncation]

```
% MATLAB R2018b
mu = 0; sigma = 1;
pdN = makedist('Normal',mu,sigma);
pdHN = truncate(pdN,0,inf);

X = (-4:.01:4)';
Xt = X(X>0);

figure, hold on, box on
p(1) = plot(X,pdf(pdN,X),'k-','DisplayName','Normal')
p(2) = plot(Xt,pdf(pdHN,Xt),'b-','DisplayName','HalfNormal')
YAxis = get(gca,'YTick');
plot([0;0],[0,YAxis(end)],'b--','HandleVisibility','off')
legend('show')
set(p,'LineWidth',1.8)
ylabel('Probability Density Function (PDF)')
```

[image: Logical Indexing]

```
Y = random(pdN,50000,1);
Yt = Y(Y>0);

figure, hold on, box on
histogram(Y,'Normalization','pdf','FaceColor','k','DisplayName','Normal')
histogram(Yt,'Normalization','pdf','FaceColor','b','DisplayName','HalfNormal')
legend('show')
```